# JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: can't call void android.view.View.setTranslationZ(float) on null object

Tags: android, animation, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a complex app and having this error when tapping on a button which triggers two views to appear via FadeIn- and TranslateX-animation. The views have been loaded before and have also been inserted into the layout (as invisible). Lateron when running the app I tap the button and the error appears.

Here's the stacktrace:

```
11-07 10:42:08.986 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: can't call void android.view.View.setTranslationZ(float) on null object
11-07 10:42:08.986 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     in call to CallVoidMethodV
11-07 10:42:08.986 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     from void android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.nCallFloatMethod(java.lang.Object, long, float)
11-07 10:42:08.986 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
11-07 10:42:08.986 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x87394ef0 self=0xb4e08000
11-07 10:42:08.986 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | sysTid=29902 nice=0 cgrp=apps sched=0/0 handle=0xb6f18ec8
11-07 10:42:08.986 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | state=R schedstat=( 12655665356 2452371955 8477 ) utm=1045 stm=220 core=0 HZ=100
11-07 10:42:08.986 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | stack=0xbe53f000-0xbe541000 stackSize=8MB
11-07 10:42:08.986 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
11-07 10:42:08.986 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #00 pc 00004640  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (UnwindCurrent::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+23)
11-07 10:42:08.986 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #01 pc 00002e8d  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (Backtrace::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+8)
11-07 10:42:08.986 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #02 pc 00245eb1  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, char const*, art::mirror::ArtMethod*)+68)
11-07 10:42:08.986 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #03 pc 0022ad0f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const+146)
11-07 10:42:08.986 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #04 pc 000b0beb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+582)
11-07 10:42:08.996 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #05 pc 000b1325  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbortF(char const*, char const*, ...)+60)
11-07 10:42:08.996 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #06 pc 000b1601  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::CheckVirtualMethod(_jobject*, _jmethodID*)+408)
11-07 10:42:08.996 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #07 pc 000bb917  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::CallVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+70)
11-07 10:42:08.996 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #08 pc 00063303  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
11-07 10:42:08.996 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #09 pc 00071e8d  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (Java_android_animation_PropertyValuesHolder_nCallFloatMethod__Ljava_lang_Object_2JF+132)
11-07 10:42:08.996 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.nCallFloatMethod(Native method)
11-07 10:42:08.996 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.access$400(PropertyValuesHolder.java:38)
11-07 10:42:08.996 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder$FloatPropertyValuesHolder.setAnimatedValue(PropertyValuesHolder.java:1296)
11-07 10:42:08.996 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.animateValue(ObjectAnimator.java:952)
11-07 10:42:08.996 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.animation.ValueAnimator.animationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:1207)
11-07 10:42:08.996 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.animation.ValueAnimator.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:1248)
11-07 10:42:08.996 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:659)
11-07 10:42:08.996 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.run(ValueAnimator.java:682)
11-07 10:42:08.996 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
11-07 10:42:08.996 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
11-07 10:42:08.996 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:559)
11-07 10:42:08.996 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
11-07 10:42:08.996 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-07 10:42:08.996 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-07 10:42:08.996 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
11-07 10:42:08.996 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6066)
11-07 10:42:08.996 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
11-07 10:42:08.996 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-07 10:42:08.996 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
referenceTable GDEF length=778 1
referenceTable GSUB length=6388 1
referenceTable GPOS length=66796 1
referenceTable GDEF length=372 1
referenceTable GSUB length=17802 1
referenceTable GPOS length=89498 1
referenceTable GSUB length=11222 1
referenceTable GPOS length=9574 1
referenceTable head length=54 1
referenceTable GDEF length=22 1
referenceTable GSUB length=1206 1
referenceTable GPOS length=12 1
referenceTable GSUB length=11222 1
referenceTable GPOS length=9574 1
referenceTable head length=54 1
referenceTable head length=54 1
referenceTable GSUB length=14200 1
referenceTable GPOS length=26192 1
referenceTable head length=54 1
referenceTable GSUB length=11222 1
referenceTable GPOS length=9574 1
referenceTable head length=54 1
referenceTable GSUB length=11222 1
referenceTable GPOS length=9574 1
referenceTable head length=54 1
11-07 10:42:08.996 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
11-07 10:42:08.996 F/art     (29902): sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]
```

Strange thing about this is, the occurance of this error is highly dependent on the built codebase. If I comment out a line (e.g. only one of the views are animated in, or a method call to one of the views) it does not happen. E.g. I stumbled on this error a time ago, changed the layout a bit, it didn't happen anymore, and now it's back. Furthermore it seems to be dependent on the device!? It appeared in the emulator, but now its only appearing on my Samsung S5 device (API 21, Forms 2.3.3-pre4). But if the error occurs it happens as a result of the same action every time (first tap on same button).

SetTranslationZ as I understand it, is responsible for setting the depth-index of a view within it's parent. However I do not knowingly change that.

Can anyone point me in a direction on what else I can try? Could the view be disposed, while being still in the parental RelativeLayout but being invisible?

Comment: Are you using recylerview-multiselect ?

Comment: can you share some cod?

Comment: I'm not using a recyclerview. I've switched to a workaround using PlatformEffects - unfortunately running into another bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=46924